# Keeping data between ActionResults

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, tempdata

I am populating a list based on data returned from a stored procedure, this first occurs in the SpecificArea ActionResult:

```
public ActionResult SpecificArea(ModelCallDetails call, int id = 0 )
    {

        ReturnSpecificAreas(call, id);
        return PartialView("SpecificArea", listCallDetails);
    }
```

When the list is displayed each row is an actionlink, which will sends the data to the SpecificAreaWorker:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult SpecificAreaWorker(ModelCallDetails call, int id)
    {           
        TempData["StringOfIds"] = StringOfIds;
        ReturnSpecificAreas(call, id);
        if (ResponseMessage == "Successful")
        {



            return PartialView("SpecificArea", listCallDetails);
        }

        else
        {

            return RedirectToAction("ViewCall");


        }

    }
```

I am wanting to collect the id of each row that is clicked and store them in a list in the model so that I can create a  string of id's. However, each time a row in the table is clicked it refreshes the model, and I no longer have a list of ids anymore.

```
  public void ReturnSpecificAreas(ModelCallDetails call, int id)

    {

        SelectedAffectedServiceID = id;
       call.AffectedServiceList.Add(SelectedAffectedServiceID);

        foreach (int item in call.AffectedServiceList)
        {
            if (TempData["StringOfIds"] != null)
            {
                StringOfIds = TempData["StringOfIds"].ToString();
                StringOfIds += string.Join(",", call.AffectedServiceList.ToArray());

            }

            else
            {

                StringOfIds += string.Join(",", call.AffectedServiceList.ToArray());
            }

        }
```

I have tried to mantain the data in tempdata, but can't manage to execute this -will the tempdata refresh each time the actionlink is clicked?  Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are using MVC5? If so, use

> System.Web.HttpContext

This gets current request

to save....

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application["StringOfIds"] =  StringOfIds;  //Saves global
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["StringOfIds"] =  StringOfIds;  //Saves Session
```

To retrieve...

```
StringOfIds = (string) System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application ["StringOfIds"]; //Retrieves from global memory
StringOfIds = (string) System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session ["StringOfIds"]; //retrieves from session memory
```

Good luck.

Comment: This answer is correct.  `Application` is global state, and `Session` is per-session state.